# CheckBox с тремя состояниями

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

Возможно ли создать CheckBox с тремя состояниями: не установлено, включено, исключено?
Что-то вроде того, что ниже: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть свойство специально для этого **IsThreeState**

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox 
       Content="CheckBox" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Margin="0,0,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       IsThreeState="True" 
       Indeterminate="CheckBox_Indeterminate" 
       Checked="CheckBox_Checked" 
       Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"
    />
</Grid>
```

MainWindowXaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Indeterminate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Title = "Неопределено";
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Title = "Выбран";
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Title = "Не выбран";
    }
}
```

Если нужно с картинками, задаем свой стиль

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image x:Name="checkBoxImage" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/uncheck.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/check.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="checkBoxImage" Property="Source" Value="/Images/indeterminate.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Осталось только иконку черного квадрата заменить на крестик. Не знаете как это сделать?

Comment: Создайте стиль с нужными картинками(иконками), я дополнил ответ.

Comment: добавил стиль и теперь содержимое Content чекбокса не отображается, только сама иконка =/

Comment: Дополнил, теперь текст будет отображаться. По svg не подскажу, скорей всего его нужно конвертировать в xaml прежде чем использовать.

Comment: так xaml тоже не пашет.. image не принимает в качестве source иконку xaml =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest ну так используйте другой элемент, который принимает

Comment: @Mr.Modest или просто положите рядом три элемента и меняйте их видимость через тригеры

Comment: @PavelMayorov а вы случайно не знаете, какой поддерживает?

Comment: @Mr.Modest зависит от того, что вы понимаете под "иконкой xaml"

Comment: @Mr.Modest в любом случае, если у вас есть отдельная иконка xaml и вы не можете ее отобразить - к чек-боксу это не имеет ни малейшего отношения

Comment: заработало) разве что вначале идёт false, затем true. нельзя как-то задать последовательность смены значений? а то получается, чтобы включить пункт надо 2 раза нажать, а исключить 1 раз =/

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, определите свой стиль. Пример:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="imageCheckBox" Width="30" Height="30" />
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" Property="Source" Value="..." />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" Property="Source" Value="..." />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" >
                        <Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" Property="Source" Value="..." />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[Источник](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ff2bacd-e1a2-4d76-81a0-62fe0428a555/custom-checkbox-with-three-states?forum=wpf)

Привязку чекбокса нужно сделать к Nullable полю типа `bool?`.

Comment: то есть можно сделать соответствие: `null - не установлено`, `true - включено`, `false - исключено`?

Comment: `<Setter TargetName="imageCheckBox" Property="Source" Value="..." />` - я правильлно понимаю, что здесь в Value должен быть путь иконки состояния checkbox?

Comment: @Mr.Modest Да, триггер будет отрабатывать при изменении значения и устанавливать нужную картинку.

Comment: @Mr.Modest да, все правильно

Comment: можно в value задать векторное изображение xaml? Если да, то как? Или только обычные изображения аля png поддерживает?

Comment: @Mr.Modest В Value вы также можете указать ресурс с векторным изображением `Value="{StaticResource ...}"`

Comment: спасибо) вернусь домой и попробую)

Comment: не совсем понял. Куда лучше вставить стиль?  Пытался добавить в StackPanel, в котором лежит checkbox, но выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57732/discussion-between-ruslan-artamonov-and-mr-modest).

Answer (score 1):

мне как то понадобился `CheckBox` с тремя состояниями для вставки в дерево в итоге сложный переключатель и возможность использовать доп пояснение, кликабельное

```
<Style x:Key="triple_violet_CheckBoxStyleChange12"
           TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="White"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayBrushdiabled" Color="#FF8B8B8B"/>


                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrushdisabled" Color="#FF8B8B8B"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayBrush" Color="#FF726E6E"/>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearBrushBlue" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3A7BC4" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4683C3" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B9FEA" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF86BAFA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearBrushViolet" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3945C1" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4651C3" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B6DEA" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8688FA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearBrushGray" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop x:Name="Gradient1" Color="#FF606060" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop x:Name="Gradient2" Color="#FF9A9A9A" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop x:Name="Gradient3" Color="#FFD3D2D3" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearBrushBluediabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF334E6C" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF435E7A" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B7EA4" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF6A86AA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearVioletBrushBluediabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF331C6C" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF432C7A" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B42A4" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF6A4AAA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearBrushGraydiabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF323131" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF838383" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA8A5A8" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BulletDecorator Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


                            <!--<Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                       Margin="0,0" Padding="5,2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>-->
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Width="90" Height="20"
                                    CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1" 
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" Background="{StaticResource LinearBrushGray}"
                                    Cursor="Hand">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <!--<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>-->
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="#CCAAAAAA" Direction="10"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Label Name="BooleanContent" 
                                           Content="Не выбрано" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="2,0,2,0" Padding="0"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" FontSize="12"  />
                            </Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentControl Name="Contentcontent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Contentcontent"  Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>


                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Выбрано все"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearBrushBlue}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect  Color="#CCAAAAAA" Direction="10"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Не выбрано"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GrayBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearBrushGray}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>

                                    <DropShadowEffect  Color="#CCAAAAAA" Direction="10"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>


                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Выборочно"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearBrushViolet}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect  Color="#CCAAAAAA" Direction="10"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>


                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Выбрано все"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrushdisabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearBrushBluediabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>

                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Выборочно"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrushdisabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearVioletBrushBluediabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>

                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Content" Value="Не выбрано"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BooleanContent" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GrayBrushdiabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border"         Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LinearBrushGraydiabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"/>

                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```