# Какую панель лучше выбрать внутрь ScrollViewer'а?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, scrollview

Есть вот такое окно (упрощено):

```
<Window>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <!--Some controls-->
        </DockPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                  Background="#FFF8F8F8">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:MangaShortInfoControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">Фильтры</TextBlock>
            <Separator />
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--Some controls-->
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Выглядит оно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы, чтобы при уменьшении размера окна на панели с фильтрами появлялся ползунок и её можно было скролить.

Как я понял, StackPanel в моём случае не очень подходит. Использовать тот же Grid сомнительно и громоздко, ибо фильтров (а значит и control'ов) много и их количество может варьироваться.

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы появлялся Scroll?

Comment: Обычно практически всегда использую Grid и доволен этим. Вы не думали поместить виды фильтров в Expande?

Comment: во всяком случае от `StackPanel` больше вреда чем пользы

Comment: @FoggyFinder, а что есть Expande? Какой-то особенный control для фильтров? Сейчас у меня фильтры это набор checkbox'ов забинденных со словарём =/

Comment: конечно, же `Expander`, не ноутбук старый не всегда все буквы пропечатываются

Comment: https://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html

Comment: вот на русском - https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level6/6_14.php

Comment: " Сейчас у меня фильтры это набор checkbox'ов забинденных со словарём =/" checkBox? не radioButton?

Comment: @FoggyFinder круглые жирные - потому что кастомный стиль.. у них три состояния..
последний фильтр (сортировка) уже radioButton

Comment: @FoggyFinder если интересно, то тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658669/checkbox-с-тремя-состояниями

Comment: @FoggyFinder Expander это круто и красиво, но не уверен, что это полностью избавит от необходимости скролла.. Если пользователь раскроет Expander, то для отображения всего его содержимого, может понадобится скролл =/

Comment: @FoggyFinder или вы предлагаете запихнуть категории в Expander, а их уже в Grid?

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли

Comment: btw, если у вас будут подобные небольшие вопросы можете пинговать меня сразу в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) при первой возможности отвечу

Comment: @FoggyFinder спасибо, буду иметь в виду)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @FoggyFinder, я узнал про такую чудесную вещь, как Expander и смог сократить число control'ов.

Переделал в коде вот эту часть (2 строка, 2 столбец глобального Grid):

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">Фильтры</TextBlock>
    <Separator />
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <!--Some controls-->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

На вот это:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Margin="5,0">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" Margin="5">Фильтры</TextBlock>
            <Separator />
        </StackPanel>

        <Expander Grid.Row="1">
            <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black">Статус</TextBlock>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <!--Some controls-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Grid.Row="2">
            <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black">Тип</TextBlock>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <!--Some controls-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Grid.Row="3">
            <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black">Сортировка</TextBlock>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <!--Some controls-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

То есть, убрал внешний StackPanel, тот StackPanel, что внутри ScrollViewer заменил на Grid, а заголовок занёс как первую строчку. Кучу контролов я разбил на несколько Expander и также занёс их в Grid в строки..

Теперь скролл появляется)